# Validar Decimales en ForRequest de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validación, formrequest

Estoy trabajando con unos formularios pero tengo el problema de que al validad desde backend con el FormRequest no me resulta el ingreso de valores decimales hasta el rango que lo necesito, actualmente lo tengo asi:

`"numberdecimal" => "required|numeric|between:0,99.99",`

por un motivo que no entiendo no me deja agregar valores mayor a 1 entero, lo que necesito es que me permita agregar valores entre 0.10000 hasta los 100.0000, me refiero entre cero y cien, pero con decimales claramente

Como debo hacerlo?

he probado de esta forma pero me sigue retorando error...

```
"numberdecimal" => "required|numeric|between:0.0,100",
```

Actualmente me esta retornando este error

```
local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'numberdecimal' at row 1 (SQL: update `my_table` set `numberdecimal` = 10.9999
```

Comment: `between:0,100` no te funciona?

Comment: Nada la verdad, actualice el post, agregando el error que me esta arrojando!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno mi codigo la verdad esta bien, revisando mas a fondo y haciendo pruebas me doy cuenta que mi error lo traia en mi mi columna de mi tabla, lo tenia como `decimal(4,4)`    y lo he pasado a `decimal(8,4)` con esto solucione el problema, si mal no me equivoco es que el lago maximo de digitos seran 8 y con 4 de ellos como decimales! si me equivoco por favor me corrigen en este detalle.

y bueno si a alguien le sirve, aca hay mas detalles [Trabajando con decimales en mysql](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2017/09/22/entendiendo-tipo-dato-decimal-en-mysql/)